# Collections Greyed Out

Tags: collections

I just opened up one of my old Blender files from 2017 in Blender 4.0 and I found that I can't see the items in most collections in the viewports. I'm assuming the compatibility attempted to take the old layers system and transfer them to collections. But either way, no matter what I click, I can't seem to "un-grey-out" these collections...

[image]

Any thoughts?

Thanks!
Anson

Comment: There might be an easier way to do this. If you right click on the greyed out collection, it opens a menu, choose Visibility->Enable in Viewports. I only did a quick test with this, so FWIW.

Comment: A bit of a follow up to what @Blunder said. I think that you will find the accepted answer in the linked thread will give you a much easier way to make the items visible that my suggested method. You will find after turning on that option that there is a RESTRICT_VIEW_ON icon in most all the rows of your Collections. You just have to click on it to make the items you want visible. The other rows with visible collections will have a RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF icon. I only add this because for me I thought the wording of the answer could have been a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out, this is a duplicate! :)